# Java8 UnitTesting CompletableFuture Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous

I'm using CompletableFuture Java8 class to make network calls asynchronously in Java, specifically using the `supplyAsync()` method. It's working great. I've figured out that I can unit test the "happy path" scenarios using `CompletableFuture.completedFuture()`. What I'm trying to figure out is how to unit test (if possible) the cases where an exception (i.e. `CompletionException`, `InterruptedException`, or `ExecutionException`) is thrown during the async task.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture was a starting point and useful source but doesn't address this question.

My first approach does not compile:

`final CompletableFuture<ResponseType> completableFutureException =
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new InterruptedException());`

My second approach predictably generates a `ClassCastException` at runtime: 
`final CompletableFuture completableFutureException =
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new InterruptedException());`

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.InterruptedException cannot be cast to ResponseType`

It also sounds like the `CompletableFuture<U> newIncompleteFuture()` method in Java9 might help - alas, we are stuck on Java8 for the moment. If Java9 would help me here, I'd still appreciate knowing.

As I've said, I'd like to figure out if there is a reasonable way to test this in Java8 (preferably without using PowerMock, as we've had trouble getting that to play nicely with Gradle). If this really just isn't unit-testable, I can accept that and move on.

Comment: can you show your original code using `supplyAsync`

Comment: Not sure how it's relevant. I have a generic method that allows any `Function` to be run asynchronously. These functions are making an external API call and may throw an exception if that external dependency doesn't return the expected data. I can trigger this manually by giving it a bad call to make, and I see the exception code triggering and doing exactly what I expect. What I'm looking for is a way to unit test that process.

```
try {
  completableFuture.get();
}
catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
      //How do I get a unit test in here?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 9 introduced a new method [failedFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture(java.lang.Throwable)) to meet this need. You can easily create your own equivalent method if you're running Java 8.

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> failedFuture(Throwable ex) {
    // copied from Java 9 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture(java.lang.Throwable)
    CompletableFuture<T> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.completeExceptionally(ex);
    return f;
}

CompletableFuture<ResponseType> failure = failedFuture(new InterruptedException());
```

Alternatively you can use supplyAsync:

```
CompletableFuture<ResponseType> failure = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {throw new InterruptedException();})
```

Comment: Supplying a InterruptedException within supplyAsync function won''t work as it is a checked exception, so the compiler will force you to create a try/catch so that option won't work. The failed future will also not work because it will be wrapped in a ExecutionException.